# Probability question about picking balls in a subset

Tags: probability

If there are 30 numbered balls how do I figure out what the odds are that if I draw 5 at least 2 will be between 1 and 20?

I'm really looking for how to solve this generically.  If there are N balls and I draw X, how do I know that at least Y will be between 1 and N-M?

Comment: I started down this path but immediately started second guessing myself:
The odds of getting 1 ball between 1 and 20 is 20/30.  
The odds of getting at least 1 ball between 1 and 20 with 2 choices is 1 - (10/30)*(9/30). Is that right or is it 1-(10/30)*(10/30)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tedious but doable. The opposite of "at least 2 out of 5" is "either 0 or 1 out of 5" and that is slightly easier to calculate.

The probability the first ball is NOT between 1 and 20 (inclusive?) is 10/30= 1/3.  There are then 9 numbers left that are not between 1 and 20 and 29 balls altogether.  The probability the next ball is not between 1 and 20 is 9/29.  Continuing in that way it is easy to see that the probability the third ball drawn is not between 1 and 20 is 8/28, the probability the fourth ball drawn is not between 1 and 20 is 7/27, and the probability the fifth ball drawn is not between 1 and 20 is 6/26.

The probability that, in 5 picks, **none** of the balls is between 1 and 20 is (10/30)(9/29)(8/28)(7/27)(6/26).

Now look at one being between 1 and 20.  As before the probability of the first 4 balls not being between 1 and 20 is (10/30)(9/29)(8/28)(7/27).  The probability the last ball **is** between 1 and 20 is not 10/26 so the probability of "NNNNY" (with "N" representing "not between 1 and 20" and "Y" representing "between 1 and 20) **in that order** is (10/30)(9/29)(8/28)(7/27)(10/26).

But it is easy to see that the probabilities of "NNNYN", "NNYNN", "NYNNN", and "YNNNN" are exactly the same.  The probability of either 0 or 1 number between 1 and 20 is (10/30)(9/29)(8/28)(7/27)(6/26)+ 5(10/30)(9/29)(8/28)(7/27)(10/26).

The probability of "two or more numbers are between 1 and 20" is 1 minus that.

Comment: Awesome explanation!  Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

Answer on your generic question:
$$\sum_{y=Y}^X\frac{\binom{N-M}{y}\binom{M}{X-y}}{\binom{N}{X}}$$where $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $k\notin\{0,1,\dots,n\}$

[Hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).